# anaconda3 doesnt create lacation, so after restart pc conda not found on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda

**!Problem solved**

I have download anaconda and everything have worked, but after restart pc it could not found anaconda and conda's commands:

```
$ conda info
< conda: command not found
```

I realize that despite that I've chosen:

```
Anaconda3 will be installed into this location: /home/name/anaconda3
- press ENTER to confirm
>>> ENTER
```

the folder anaconda3 hadn't been created.

Answer (score 0):

version I used: Anaconda3-2011.11

**possible solutions:**

You should type anaconda3 instead of ENTER. When you type ENTER, ENTER will be directory you've chosen (probably a bug). Beside that part of files won't be installed (or I don't where they were, but I am sure they weren't where they should)

2. All successful installations were from *anaconda installer* (instead of *curl*)
3. Before shutting down PC I used command:

```
$ anaconda-navigator
```

After this action every folder was created like it should and conda is found event after restarting PC.